# Spark scala, filtered result size larger than original data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

have meet some confusion about filter. 
There is an RDD val names words as following:

```
Array(Array('1239423', '42132'), Array('245123', '32412'), ...)
```

The first element is userid and the second is item id.

And a array of valid item ids in another val trainitemids_value as following:

```
Array('42132', '43123', ...)
```

I want to use this valid id set to apply filter on words.
As I understand, the number of output of following 2 methods should be same:

```
val ids = words.map(line => line(1))
val re = ids.filter(line => trainitemids_value.contains(line))\
```

or

```
val re = words.filter(line => trainitemids_value.contains(line(1)))
```

But actually it's different. The number of method 1 make sense, because it's smaller than the number of original words.
The method 2's result has a much larger number compare to original words.

I don't understand how come the number of output of filter can be larger than original collections?

Following is the original output from my console:

```
scala> val ids = words.map(line => line(1))
ids: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[14] at map at <console>:28
scala> val re = ids.filter(line => validID.contains(line))
re: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[15] at filter at <console>:42
scala> re.count()
res4: Long = 42548
scala> val re2 = words.filter(line => validID.contains(line(1)))
re2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[16] at filter at <console>:40
scala> re2.count()
res5: Long = 2448569
scala> words.count()
res6: Long = 42549
```

According to @vindev 's answer, I tried cached the words RDD. The result looks reasonable now. I still don't fully understand the cause through.
Following is the solution:

```
scala> val cached = words.cache
cached: words.type = MapPartitionsRDD[13] at map at <console>:26

scala> cached.count()
res7: Long = 42549`
scala> val re3 = cached.filter(line => validID.contains(line(1)))
re3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[17] at filter at <console>:42
scala> re3.count()
res8: Long = 42548
```

Comment: what's wrong with words.filter(word => validID.map(_ == word.id))?

Comment: In your first code you are filtering `Array[String]` as you are extracting index `1` from your `Array[Array[String]]` hence it will result in `Array[String]`, unlike in the second case where you are filtering whole `Array[Array[String]]` and it will produce complete `Array[Array[String]]`

Comment: @vindev Yes I understand the difference. It means the number of columns of 2 outputs are different. But I expect the same number of rows for both case. And in fact the number of rows are different, which confused me. BTW, I used re.count() to calculate the number of rows.

Comment: @user10837555 I ran with the data given in the question as it ran as expected. Result is one row in both the cases. There might be something else causing issue.

Comment: @RamanMishra It will give a type mismatch error because filter expect each lambda return a single boolean. And validID.map(_ == word.id) will return a Array of boolean. And it's very slow because it's compare each element of validID with word.id, instead of just check if the id in valid ids.

Comment: use contains or exists

Comment: @vindev Yes it is very weird. I have post the original output from my console in the question.

Comment: @RamanMishra Hi Raman, no offense, but contains is what I used in my original code in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @user10837555 from where are you reading this data? can you try caching words RDD so that it is not computed again. Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @vindev I read from a text file on HDFS. Amazingly the caching works. I still don't understand why. I will pick your answer because it works. Thank you.

Comment: One reason might be that the source changed while running your second piece of code. As as you were not caching so Spark  re-calculates the whole DAG and hence end up reading the updated record in the file. But when you cache your RDD Spark reads the file only one time and don't need to re-calculate it for your Second transformation.

Comment: @vindev I understand that caching will affect the speed. Caching some mid point results to avoid duplicate calculation and optimize efficiency. But I didn't expect caching could lead to different results. This is so anti-intuition to me :-)

Comment: @user10837555 : You could submit a issue to the spark on github if you really think it a bug. Would be helpful for others.